# $P'(x)$ is the derivative of polynomial $P(x)$ to $x$.

Tags: analysis, derivatives, polynomials

What is the remainder of $P(x)$ divided by $(x-a)^2$.
The options are
$P'(a)(x-a) + P(a)$

$2P'(a)(x-a) + P(a)$

$P'(a)P(a)(x-a) + P(a)$

$P'(a)(x-a)^2$

$P'(a)(x-a)^2 + P(a)$

What is the relation of the derivative of polynomial to the remainder?

What i know is, the value when $ x $ is the factor of the divisor is the remainder, $P(a) = $ the remainder of $P(x)$ divided by $(x-a)^2$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $P(x)=Q(x)(x-a)^2+bx+c.$

Thus, $$P(a)=ba+c$$ and
$$P'(a)=\left(Q'(x)(x-a)^2+2Q(x)(x-a)+b\right)_{x=a}=b,$$ which gives
$$c=P(a)-aP'(a).$$
Id est, we got the following remainder. 
$$P'(a)x+P(a)-aP'(a)$$ or
$$P'(a)(x-a)+P(a).$$

Comment: How we sure it is bx + c not bx^2 + cx + d? Or sure p(x ) has 3rd degree, not 4 etc

Comment: @Lifeforbetter The degree of the remainder should be less than a degree of $(x-a)^2,$ which is $2$.

Answer (score 1):

Without loss of generality, we can work with $a=0$, by shifting the variable.

The remainder of $P(x)$ divided by $x^2$ is $p_1x+p_0$ (the low order terms), and it is virtually immediate that

$$R(x)=P'(0)x+P(0).$$

Now with $a\ne0$,

$$R(x)=P'(a)(x-a)+P(a).$$

Comment: I like your answer too.. but i am not sure using it if i got different equation for the polynomials. For example, how if the divisor is $x+3$ and the polynomial $p(x)$ how do we find the remainder using your appoarched ?

Comment: @Lifeforbetter: $P'(a)(x-a)+P(a)$, as written.

Answer (score 0):

$P(x)=(x-2)^2q(x)+cx+d$, remainder is a polynomial of at most degree one.

Need to calculate $c$ and $d$.

1)$P(a)=ca+d$;

$d=P(a)-ca$;

2)$P'(x)=2(x-a)q(x)+(x-a)^2q'(x)+c;$

$c= P'(a);$

$d=P(a)-P'(a)a$;

Remainder :

$cx+d=P'(a)x+P(a)-P'(a)a=P'(a)(x-a)+P(a)$.